# Unable to restore Gitlab (VM, Docker) but tar file looks ok

Tags: docker, gitlab, restore

We're working with GitLab 8.16.4 and I want to upgrade it but since the backups are not compatible between versions I want to make sure everything is ok first.

I've been trying to follow the recovery process in a VM (VirtualBox) and in a few Dockers and is not giving any error but not working either ([opened an issue there too](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/46988)  )

I don't know what to check, what I'm doing wrong or if I need to do anything specific  on the GitLab server (backup job> gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create SKIP=db,uploads )

Any ideas?

Note regarding the VM: This was created in the past to have a backup of GitLab and it did do the restore months ago, not sure what's going on now

Edit days later: Installed the whole thing on a physical server with Ubuntu 16.04, still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it work!!

Looks like the problem was on the way I was making the backup.

After doing it with:

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

The restore worked fine with:

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=<filename>
```